# Add selected data from one table to another table using 'onclick button HTML

Tags: php, mysql

My project is about Allergies and I am trying to add the allergies given in one table "List of Allergies" to another table "MyAllergies" with an onclick button "add" for each allergies given. What I want is when the user clicks on add button for one allergy, that specific allergy should automatically be added to the "MyAllergy.php". Please help me. I have been trying for 2 days and I got no where. However, I tried the query and it was almost correct. I would be so grateful. Thank you. Let me know if you want me to attach the other code or any more questions. :)

**AddAllergy.php**

```
<?php 
include('Session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Allergen Details</title>
<div align="center">
<h1>Allergen Information</h1> 
</div>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $allergysql = 'SELECT Allergy,Description,Symptoms FROM FoodAllergy';
    $retrieve = mysqli_query($connection, $allergysql);
    if(!$retrieve)
    {
        die("Could not get data!".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    print " 
    <table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"7\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse\" bordercolor=\"#85144b\" width=\"100&#37;\" id=\"AutoNumber2\" bgcolor=\"#7FDBFF\"><tr> 
    <th width=100>Allergy:</th> 
    <th width=100>Description:</th> 
    <th width=100>Symptoms:</th> 
    <th width=100>Status:</th> 
    </tr>";
    while($rowA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retrieve))
    {
       print "<tr>"; 
       print "<td>" . $rowA['Allergy'] . "</td>"; 
       print "<td>" . $rowA['Description'] . "</td>"; 
       print "<td>" . $rowA['Symptoms'] . "</td>"; ?>
<td> <div align ="center"> <button type ="button" onclick="addallergy()">Add</button></div></td>
<script>
    function addallergy() {
        // WHAT SHOULD I ADD HERE?? //
        alert ('Added to your profile!');
    }
        </script>
   <?php 
       print "</tr>"; 
    } 
       print "</table>"; 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either you use a form and submit it with a submit button, or use Ajax...

Comment: @developerwjk Thank you, I will try but is there a way if I use the function in the '<script>' right now.

Comment: You can put an ajax call in your `addallergy` method.

Comment: @developerwjk I have never used ajax, any hint of where to look or could you help me please?

Comment: For the least amount of work, look into jquery's `$.ajax()` method.

Comment: @developerwjk Thank you, also can you help me with the query that I could carry out my this goal.. I would really appreciate it.